# Lyx no preferences menu

Tags: lyx

I began to use Lyx in Mac (I've used it in Windows 10)

The problem is, I'd like to define some shortcuts I used to use, and I think I could change them in 'Tools -> Preferences' menu.

But my mac shows no preferences menu on tools. It has only Spellcheckers, Thesaurus, Statistics, TEX informations, Compare, and Reconfigure.
How do I define customized shortcut in such a situation?

Comment: There should definitely be a preferences menu entry somewhere. I think on macOS, it might be under the "LyX" menu. Does that work?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes. Thanks. Now I feel foolish...

Comment: It's unfortunate that it's not the same on all OS. Also, some of the LyX documentation refers to Tools > Preferences, without mentioning the special macOS case. So don't blame yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows and Linux, there is a "Tools" menu that indeed contains "Preferences". However, on macOS, "Preferences" is under the "LyX" menu. I believe this is the standard on macOS.